# How to export from Illustrator to Photoshop and preserve the artboard structure?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, export, artboard

The app *zeplin.io* is a tool that provides developers with information about a design, such as positioning and colors. But it works exclusively with Photoshop and Sketch. I would like to know if there is a way to take an Illustrator file with artboard, export it to a Photoshop file with artboards, and then import it to Zeplin.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an AI file to PSD simply click `File > Export As... > PSD`. In the Photoshop Export Options pop-up menu, select `Write Layers` and `Maximum Editability` then click `OK`. After that open this file in Photoshop.

[image]